# Bounding variance with supremum

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, variance

Let $f:[0,1]^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $D = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be some real independent random variables in $[0,1]$.

I need to bound:

$$
\mathbb{E}_D\left[\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x,x_i)-E[f(x,x_i)]\right)^2\right]
$$
Is there any chance to bound this expectation by something like
$$
\frac{c}{n}\operatorname{Var}\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x,x_1)\right).
$$

Any suggestions are very appreciated!
Thanks.